# How to close a child pop up which appears on same page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup, webdriver

I want to close this pop up. Its not a alert, not in Frame or not a window. I am able to close it `Robot` class but PM said its not the right practice to use `Robot` class in this case.

So how can I close this?

I tried many times but didn't get success.

See image :-

[image: https]

HTML:

```
<div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1473662523684_188" class="page-popup-container-content modal-content yui3-widget-stdmod yui3-widget-content-expanded">
<div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1473662523684_365" class="yui3-widget-hd modal-header">
<div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1473662523684_293" class="toolbar-content yui3-widget component toolbar">
<button id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1473662523684_367" class="btn close close-content yui3-widget btn-content btn-focused" type="button">×</button>
</div>
<h3 id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1473662523684_366">Security Tips</h3>
</div>
<div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1473662523684_344" class="yui3-widget-bd modal-body" style="max-height: 450px; height: 365px;">
<div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1473662523684_501" class="pop-contain">
<div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1473662523684_527" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 1em;">
<button id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1473662523684_526" class="lgnBtn btn btnPrimary" type="button" onclick="closepopup1();">Close</button>
```

Tried code with `selenium` :-

```
WebDriver driver; driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
driver.get("brcp.infoaxon.com"); 

String currentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[1]/a")).click(); 
Thread.sleep(1000); 
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); 
for (String handle : handles) 
{ 
  if (!handle .equals(currentHandle)) 
  { 
    driver.switchTo().window(handle); 
    driver.close(); 
  } 
  driver.switchTo().window(currentHandle); 
}
```

Comment: It's not a window popup actually, it's just message dialog you need to share this HTML as well, if you want to solution actually..

Comment: Ok, try with provided answer and let me know..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually It's not a new window popup, it is a dialog window which will popup after clicking on `Read More` button, you should simply try using `By.cssSelector()` to locate `close` button after clicking on `Read More` button with `WebDriverWait` to wait until this element visible and clickable as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

//Click on read more button to open this dialog
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Read More"))).click();

//Now wait until this dialog close button visible and clickable then click  
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.btn.close"))).click();
```

Comment: Code is working thanks. I tried with code driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'lgnBtn btn btnPrimary')]")).click() and working for this also. I think the issue was with XPath. Earlier I used XPath which is generated by Firepath. Is it true that Firepath creates issue for locate element?

Comment: From this, driver.findElement(By.id("yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1473662523684_526")).click(); its not working.. I don't know why?

Comment: @KhushbooChaudhary why are you not trying with my suggested answer using `cssSelector` instead?? and reason `By.id()` is not working because it's changing dynamically on every launch..:)

Comment: You need to use `by.cssSelctor()`instead as suggested answer..Thanks..:)

Comment: @KhushbooChaudhary, Actually, firepath just provide positional `xpath` which is not stable on dymanic case, that's why you are unable to locate element. If this answer helped to resolve you query, need [to accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as well

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like this:

```
    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    String currentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
    for (String handle : handles) {

        if (!handle .equals(currentHandle))
        {
            driver.switchTo().window(handle);
            driver.close();
        }
    }
    driver.switchTo().window(currentHandle);
```

second option:
Do this:

```
    WebElement xButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".close-content"));
    JavascriptExecuter js = (JavascriptExecuter) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", xButton);
```

Comment: Oh... from the picture I can see that this is not pop up . sorry. can you find the x button of this "dialog"?

Comment: No error. Its passed but pop up didn't close. I am using this code

Comment: WebDriver driver;
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://brcp.infoaxon.com");

String currentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[1]/a")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
for (String handle : handles) {
if (!handle .equals(currentHandle))
{
driver.switchTo().window(handle);
driver.close();
}
driver.switchTo().window(currentHandle);
}
}

Comment: @KhushbooChaudhary Edit your question and this tried attempt to your question instead of comments

Comment: Please view my second option